# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before enableSSHSFTPKeyMode'

Tags: c, enums, enumeration

I am facing problem with the use of enumeration.

Here is the code:

.h file

```
enum sshd_sftp_status
{
  SSHD_SUCCESS =0,
  SSHD_FAILED =1,
  SSHD_KEYS_NOT_INSTALLED =2,
};

extern sshd_sftp_status enableSSHSFTPKeyMode(int isSshSftpOnlyLogsActivated);
```

.c file

```
sshd_sftp_status enableSSHSFTPKeyMode(int isSshSftpOnlyLogsActivated)
{
    if(isSshSftpOnlyLogsActivated)
    {
       //code
    }
    return SSHD_SUCCESS;
}
```

With the above code, I am getting below error during compilation:

> error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before
>   'enableSSHSFTPKeyMode'

If I change the return type to `int` from `enum`, it works fine.

Help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Just precede your type name with the `enum` keyword - that's what causing your error.

```
extern enum sshd_sftp_status enableSSHSFTPKeyMode(int isSshSftpOnlyLogsActivated);

enum sshd_sftp_status enableSSHSFTPKeyMode(int isSshSftpOnlyLogsActivated)
{
    if(isSshSftpOnlyLogsActivated)
    {
       //code
    }
    return SSHD_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or use `typedef` like this - this is probably closer to what you want:

```
typedef enum 
{
    SSHD_SUCCESS =0,
    SSHD_FAILED =1,
    SSHD_KEYS_NOT_INSTALLED =2,
} sshd_sftp_status;
```

Comment: Yes .. it works.. thanks,,, but is this problem only specific to C and not in C++?? because our C++ code dont have such things.

Comment: @dragosht ... only if it is unambiguous. E.g if there are `struc stat` and function `stat` as in POSIX, `stat` refers to the function and not the type.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it happened due to forgetting `;` in last lines, for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define blabla

uint32_t i

enum{
   a=0,
   b,
   c,
};
...
```